# Change the number format change the value of the number

Tags: twig, number-formatting

I have a "salaire" object that I display on the twig side.

```
 {{ salaire.getMontant_euros_revalorise() }}
```

Note: salaire.getMontant_euros_revalorise() is a float.

it displays this :

```
20,685.05
```

It is an american display, I would like to change it to a european display meaning that the comma is a point and the point a comma.

So i tried to use this :

```
 {{ salaire.getMontant_euros_revalorise()|number_format(2, ",", ".") }}
```

Unfortunatly, it changes the value of the number. It displays this:

```
20,00
```

So from twenty thousand six hundred eighty five point zero five we go to twenty.

I dont know why it does that but does somebody know how to chnage correctly the point and comma signs ? having at the end :

```
20.685,05
```

Answer (score 0):

If `getMontant_euros_revalorise` actually returns `20,685.05` without any modification, then you have stored a `string`, not a float. So the best way to solve this, is to be sure you store the data as a real number/float rather than a string or determine where your code is already modifying the value

If this is not possible, then you would need to replace the `comma` before applying the filter.

```
{{ foo|replace({',': '',})|number_format(2, ',', '.') }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/mvurik)

Comment: you mean $salaire_revalorisation = round(floatval($salaire_euros_string) * floatval($taux_reval), 2); returns a string ?

Comment: I'm saying your output gets modified somewhere before it gets displayed. Floats are never represented with a comma. See [here](https://ideone.com/M1Hiki)

Comment: Maybe twig is doing this, getting a number, I dont know, but it does not solve my problem